# Error when building Vignette - R package development

Tags: r, knitr, devtools

My apologies in advance if this is an obvious question but I have searched both stack overflow and what have been otherwise very useful resources like [R packages](https://r-pkgs.org/) by Hadley Wickham or this [blog](https://tinyheero.github.io/jekyll/update/2015/07/26/making-your-first-R-package.html) and can not find an answer.

My issue occurs when trying to run `build_vignettes()` on my developed R package (`myPackage`). The vignette for the package (`myPackage.Rmd`) will create as expected using knit in RStudio but when I run `build_vignettes()`, I get the following error:

```
> devtools::build_vignettes()
Building cosni vignettes
--- re-building ‘myPackage.Rmd’ using rmarkdown
--- finished re-building ‘myPackage.Rmd’

Error: Directory '✓ Setting active project to \'path/to/package/directory/'' does not exist.
```

The top of my myPackage.Rmd file is:

```
---
title: "A title"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
author: "Name"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    number_sections: true
    theme: "paper"
  pdf_document:
    toc: true
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{A title}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
---
```

This file is located in the vignettes folder of my package folder. There are also 3 png images in this folder which are called in the myPackage.Rmd file as follows:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, out.width = '98%', out.height='98%'}
knitr::include_graphics("an_image.png")
```#
````

Otherwise the vignette only contains text.

The package will run and I can install it locally with either `devtools::build()` or
`devtools::install(build_vignettes = TRUE)` they will work but then when I run `browseVignettes("myPackage")` and click on the HTML, source or R code I get the following error:

> Not Found
> The requested URL /library/myPackage/doc/myPackage.html was not found on this server.

Also, in the package's DESCRIPTION file I have included the following:

```
Suggests: 
    knitr,
    rmarkdown
VignetteBuilder: knitr
```

**----------- EDIT --------------**

Through repeatedly trying to get the `devtools::build_vignettes` to work I have noted that sometimes I get the following error rather than the first I mentioned:

```
> devtools::build_vignettes()
Building cosni vignettes
--- re-building ‘myPackage.Rmd’ using rmarkdown
--- finished re-building ‘myPackage.Rmd’

Error in if (dir_exists(path %||% "") && is_in_proj(path)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the second error you get updating packages devtools and usethis.

Comment: Hi Iva, yes I came to the same conclusion on that part. Whilst I still don't know the issue with the first part I abandoned some functionality and got is to work so I'm happy to just accept this answer for the second part.